# Use Python 3 shutil to copy a file AND leave destfile writeable?

Tags: python, shutil

Is there a way to use Python 3 [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) to copy a read-only file so that the destination file does NOT receive the source file's read-only mode?

I'm successfully using *shutil* to create a working copy of a file:

```
import os, stat

inputfile = 'inputfile.json'    # A read-only file
outputfile = 'outputfile.json'  # A file I want to keep writeable
os.chmod(outputfile, stat.S_IWRITE)    # If outputfile exists, ensure it's writeable
shutil.copy(inputfile, outputfile)  # Rats! -- shutil included read-only attributes in copy operation
```

But *shutil* has also copied the input file's read-only attribute along with the file contents. I don't want that.

Obviously I can repeat the *os.chmod* command after the copy operation. And I know how to create a writeable copy without using *shutil*. But is it possible to use *shutil* to copy a file's contents without also copying its attributes(?)

Comment: The two answers given immediately below by Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams and Rolf of Saxony both work: Both shutil.copyfileobj() and shutil.copyfile() seem to be copying the file contents while leaving the destination file writeable. Not sure what I was doing wrong earlier that made me conclude they were making my destination file read-only...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the files however you like and use [`shutil.copyfileobj()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) to copy just the file contents from one to the other.

Answer (score 1):

On my linux box with python 2.7 & python3 `shutil.copyfile(inputfile, outputfile)` seems to work as well.